# Custom bottleneck in pretrained models in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to retrain Google's inception v3 for my own problem with Keras and imagenet weights. The problem is that, when you load inception v3 `imagenet` weights, you must specify that the number of classes are 1000, as follows:

```
base_network=inception_v3.InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',classes=1000)
```

If I the custom number of classes my dataset have (are not 1000), it raises an error saying that if use `imagenet` weights, you must, mandatory set `classes` to 1000.

In order to customize the top layer of inception, I've read that you can use a `bottleneck`. This is nothing more that not use the standard inception top layer and customize it, so, I can use the `include_top=False` parameter and program my own top layer.

If I do so as follows:

```
x = base_network.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(globals_params.num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
network = Model(inputs=base_network.input, outputs=predictions)
```

It works (trains) but validation loss and accuracy never change, as you can see (obviously, inception layers are set `trainable=False` in order to keep `imagenet` weights).

```
...
Epoch 00071: acc did not improve
Epoch 72/300
2741/2741 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0471 - acc: 0.9810 - val_loss: 8.5221 - val_acc: 0.4643

Epoch 00072: acc did not improve
Epoch 73/300
2741/2741 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0354 - acc: 0.9872 - val_loss: 8.4629 - val_acc: 0.4718

Epoch 00073: acc did not improve
Epoch 74/300
2741/2741 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0277 - acc: 0.9891 - val_loss: 8.2515 - val_acc: 0.4881

Epoch 00074: acc did not improve
Epoch 75/300
2741/2741 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0330 - acc: 0.9880 - val_loss: 8.5953 - val_acc: 0.4618

Epoch 00075: acc did not improve
Epoch 76/300
2741/2741 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0402 - acc: 0.9854 - val_loss: 8.3820 - val_acc: 0.4793

Epoch 00076: acc did not improve
Epoch 77/300
2741/2741 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0337 - acc: 0.9880 - val_loss: 8.1831 - val_acc: 0.4906

Epoch 00077: acc did not improve
Epoch 78/300
2741/2741 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0381 - acc: 0.9858 - val_loss: 8.4118 - val_acc: 0.4756

...
```

The question is: how can I program a top layer for inception that allows me train on my own dataset and changing my validation accuracy? I've looked for every site on the internet and I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean they don't change? In the logs that you posted validation metrics do change

Comment: Yes, I mean `val_acc` does not change significantly.